# Transforming negative correlated non linear variable to linear positive correlated variable

Tags: regression, collinearity, pearsons-correlation-coefficient

At my office, I am stuck in a weird situation. I am asked to perform a regression algorithm on the data, in which the target variable is continuous having values range between 0.6 to 0.9 with 8 digits of precision after the decimal. Although I know and have applied many linear and non-linear regression algorithms in the past the case here is something different. There is one variable, which, according to my BU, should have a positive and linear correlation with the target variable. But when I ran `Pearson's` correlation, the variable is negatively correlated and by plotting a `scatter` plot I can see that the relationship is not linear at all. 
What transformations can I perform on the variable so that it can show a positive correlation? I am fairly new to this problem so hoping to get it solved here. Thanks much everyone in advance.

Comment: In order to help can you post a sample of the correlation as well as the major parts of your code? It's rather hard to help without seeing these things. Strictly speaking, if a variable and target is not linear in a relationship then it should not be forced into one. But happy to have a look once you post as requested

Comment: Is it possible that there is a positive correlation only when controlling for some other variables? Like, eh, I bet that Walmart's global umbrella sales and rainfall aren't that correlated, but, controlling for whether it's raining or not per store per day, shows a correlation. (Poor example off the top of my head)

Comment: @IntuAi Actually I am using client's system and there are many restrictions so couldn't able to post the code and scatter plot.

The task at hand is to predict service level in order to optimize the inventories. Now service levels are the probability that tells us that the organization will not hit a stock out. The variable I am talking about is the safety stock hours(converted from safety stock). According to the BU, safety stock hours should have a positive relation with service level. But in reality that is not the case and thus I am facing difficulty to model the data

Comment: @SeanOwen I have checked with multiple combinations but couldn't able to find the required results

Answer (score 1):

What's a BU? Business Unit?

Can you tell anything about the variable and target variable? Can you include the scatter plot?

It is still not clear if the problem is not in the domain knowledge/assumptions.

A business example:
Profit depends on sales, which is generally assumed to have a positive correlation. But after a threshold marginal sales cost exceeds profits (very expensive to acquire new customers), we can still have a (local) negative correlation. If you only have data in the 'marginal' segment, you can draw incorrect conclusions.

Comment: Yes BU is Business unit. The task at hand is to predict service level in order to optimize the inventories. Now service levels are the probability that tells us that the organization will not hit a stock out. The variable I am talking about is the safety stock hours(converted from safety stock). According to the BU, safety stock hours should have a positive relation with service level. But in reality that is not the case and thus I am facing difficulty to model the data

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like there might be a (i.e., non-linear)complex relationship  between the feature and the target. If the business unit (BU) requires a positive and linear relationship between the feature and the target, you can try a [segmented regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmented_regression). There might a range of feature values that show the relationship required by the business.